# Java Regex to match a Card

Tags: java, regex

Quick question.

What's the code for Java regex that matches a string that has `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}` on the 1st char and `{S,D,C,H}` on the second. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn regular expressions.

Comment: that's why I asked. hopefully this example with help me learn more about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simple:

```
'^[1-9TJQK][SDCH]$'
```

Note that using `^` and `$` means that the string contains only two chars and respect the rules you need.

As [Jonathon Reinhart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119527/jonathon-reinhart) points out, maybe my one-line explanation is not enough. Obviously you should study in deep what that sign means. Anyway a good start point is his description:

- `^` means "at start of string"
- `[1-9TJQK]` means "any one character between 1 and 9 (inclusive) or T or J or Q or K
- `[SDCH]` Same logic as before
- `$` means "at end of string"

Comment: Note that the $ is probably what OP want (it denotes the end of the String) even though he didn't specifically say that in his post.

Comment: Explanation may help here.  '^' means "at start of string." '[1-9TJQK]' means "any one character between 1 and 9 (inclusive) or T or J or Q or K. Same logic for 'SDCH'. '$' means "at end of string."

Comment: so if i tried to do a match for "1Dx" without the $ symbol at the end I would get a match? I have tried that in java but it didn't match...

Comment: @nunos It doesn't work as you thought. If you delete the $ with this regex you still need to have the two chars from the two groups but to have other char(s) after, you have to edit the pattern. In the case of "any one or more other chars after the two I need" you have to use this pattern: [1-9TJQK][SDCH].*

Answer (score 2):

Use the following character classes:

```
[1-9TJQK][SDCH]
```

To learn more, please visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html